Solar panel charging Li-ion battery with PWM + MOSFET
My idea is to set up a circuit that uses a 18 V, 15 W solar panel to charge three 3.7 V 21700 Li-ion batteries in series (nominal voltage = 11.1 V) while the solar panel is connected directly to the batteries in parallel.
A MCU and corresponding circuit is used to monitor the voltage of the battery and generate a PWM signal to control a MOSFET which can short the solar panel with a 1 Ω, 2 W sensing resistor to ground. This resistor is also used to sense the short-circuit current of solar panel. Assume this whole circuit is working well. The parameter of this solar panel should be Voc = 21 V, Isc = 0.9 A, Impp = 0.8 A, and Vmpp = 18 V roughly.
My questions are :

I noticed lots of posts saying that the solar panel voltage will be pulled down to the battery voltage. Theoretically, if the solar panel is connected with battery in parallel, the voltage should be the same. However, in practice, the solar panel voltage is a little bit higher. Is it true? If so, is it due to the battery internal resistance?

The PWM signal generated by MCU should be digital; 0 / 3.3 V as on or off. However, I noticed some post saying the PWM can 'average' the voltage with different duty cycle. With a 50% duty cycle, is this voltage is averaged to 1.65 V? It is true when I measure with a multimeter, but I think it will be different when testing with an oscilloscope.


Assume the MOSFET fully conducts at 3.3 V. Should I say the MOSFET is not conducting at all as the Vgs is averaged to 1.65 V or I should say it is conducting for 50% of the time? I.e. does the MOSFET Vgs take the PWM as analog signal or digital? I assume the latter, because I did see a lot of MOSFET control by PWM that works well as a switch. But why? Because the MOSFET response time is short enough rather than the motor which has inertia or LED brigtness which is averaged by people's eyes?

Assume 2) answer is true and PWM is a digital signal when controlling a MOSFET. So when the MOSFET is conducting fully, it shorts the solar panel. I regard this as a function to sense the short current as well as the function of charge management because the solar panel is 'disconnected' with the battery while shorting. The duty cycle is varying according to the sensed battery voltage.

If this idea is reasonable, what is actually regulated by the PWM duty cycle? As the battery voltage will be up while charging, solar panel voltages stays the same or a bit higher, so varying duty cycle = varying charging time, and the current should be nearly constant according to the solar I-V curve. A lot of PWM controllers say voltage and current but how? In my point of view, it only regulates the charging time.

Assume 3) is true/the method of using PWM to control the MOSFET then manage the charging is working. I noticed that the resistor might heat up although the rated power is 2 W which is large enough. Assume this resistor has a small or zero temepature coefficient i.e. the resistance stayss the same no matter how heat it is. Is there another reason / advantages that I design another MOSFET in series between the solar panel and battery? Because I saw a post saying parallel control (similar as I mentioned in 3) works totally fine with small power systems if not considering the resistor heat and enery wasted. But series control has some switch losses. So for a small power system as mine, it is even worse if I design another MOSFET? I personally want to have another MOSFET so I can treat the sensing circuit and charging management circuit independently.

As I mentioned, the sensing resistor is used to measure the short current of solar panel, but the ADC of MCU should keep collecting data. If the duty cycle is 50%, can I say the ADC data collected is not accurate because it also collects the samples while the MOSFET is OFF which is 0 A if the code dies not limit the sampling to happen only while the MOSFET is conducting or without any noise filtering algorithm?


I know my post seems a little bit wordy but I really tried to explain my questions and some guessing as precise as possible.

Is there a reason you are trying to do this from scratch instead of using an integrated MPPT + battery charger chip?

The 1 Ohm resistor will also short the battery as well if solar is connected directly to battery. Why do you invent so awkward way of voltage/current regulation?

I am doing this for mainly learning purpose. I know there are a lot of MPPT solutions but thats not my aim. And as I mentioned, currently I am using the shorting method to manage charging and sensoring, but in reality the resistor will be very hot. So I am just thinking make it as series control may improve it. Or maybe not ofc.

And I forgot to mention that there should be a diode to prevent shorting the battery and reverse current while dark.
